# Handling "Page not found" using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My App.js component looks like this

```js
    <Switch>
        {loggedIn ?
          <>
            <div>
              <DashboardLayout>
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path="/my-account" component={Account} />
              </DashboardLayout>
              <Route path="/page-not-found" component={PageNotFound} />
              <Redirect from='*' to='/page-not-found' />

            </div>
          </>
          :
          <PublicRoutes />}
      </Switch>
```

My dashboardLayout has private routes in it and I want the page-not-found to be shown above it, right now it shows below it.

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [react-router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch/children-node), children of a `Switch` must be `Route` or `Redirect`.

You should create `Route`s that render components, not the other way around.

Edit: I'm not sure if React fragments (`<></>`) are part of that or not. You may want to test that or conditionally render entirely different `Switch` components/children.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. I have been stuck on this for a while now and your answer provides that shift needed to think about this problem from a different perspective. Thank you.

Comment: zbauman, I am still stuck. I might need your help here.

Comment: @thor0o0 no worries, what can I help with?

Comment: this is going to be lengthy. Please bear with me. So, I have login, forgot-password, and sign-up as public routes. Once user logs in, they go to "dashboard layout" component which has a sidebar on the left which has the menu items, the right side of the sidebar changes as per the links on it (sidebar). So, basically the private routes are rendered INSIDE dashboard layout.

Is this how you would do it too? Because when I try to redirect to the login screen from inside dashboard layout it still shows the dashboard layout because we render routes bases on "isLoggedIn".

Comment: @Thor0o0 

If I’m understanding you correctly, you maybe need to re-think the overall structure of the routes and dashboard layout... I can't type it all in a comment so I'm going to add another answer to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't fit all this in a comment, I'll add more here....

I would think something like this:

1. Have a component that can access signed in/out state. Using an if/else, check if the user is signed in and render a Switch component with private routes (described below), if they’re signed out render a Switch component with public routes (described below).
2. Each Route component is a top level child inside the above Switch that you conditionally rendered. These route components then render a “Page” component that contains your page-specific content.
3. Each page then renders a  “Wrapper” component that has things like footer, logout button, icon, etc.

```
const WrapperComponent = ({ children })=>{

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {/* ... Some content for the side bar ... */}
            </div>
            {children /* The page */}
        </>
    );

};

const SignInPage = ()=>{ /* ... */ };
const SignUpPage = ()=>{ /* ... */ };
const MyProfilePage = ()=>{ /* ... */ };
const SomePrivatePage = ()=>{

    return (
        <WrapperComponent>
            {/* ... Some page-specific content ... */}
        </WrapperComponent>
    );

};

const MainSwitchComponent = ({ isSignedIn })=>{

    if(isSignedIn){

        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/MyProfile'>
                    <MyProfilePage />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/SomePrivate'>
                    <SomePrivatePage />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        );

    }

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/SignIn'>
                <SignInPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/SignUp'>
                <SignUpPage />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    );

};
```

Ultimately it's up to you, but the Route needs to be top-level. Just keep in mind that, [per the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route), you need to use a `key` prop on the `Route` component if you are rendering the same child under multiple different Routes.

And definitely take the time to go and read the documentation from top to bottom. Most of the things I’m mentioning are in them and include examples.

Comment: I appreciate it @zbauman. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Thor0o0 no worries, good luck!